# Trying to optimize a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

**Problem**

I am trying to achieve a regular expression which matches `[0-9]:[0-9]` or `[0-9].[0-9]` or `[0-9]` or `[0-9]:` or `[0-9].`

**What I have tried**

```
/^\d?(\d+)?((\.|\:|\d)$|(\.|\:|\d)(\d+)?\d$)/
```

This regex which is satisfying my condition.

**My optimized code**

```
\d+[\.:]*\d*
```

But this is accepting `2:2:`. Actually it should not. Not able to solve this.

Comment: Try `^\d+(?:[.:]\d*)?$`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/34eznw/1).

Comment: normally regexps compile into an optimised form (A finite automaton), so why to try to optimise them yourself?  The expression you got in the first case worked, then use it.  There's no more efficiency in the second, it's simpler because it matches a simpler form of input.  As both parse input in one pass, executing the same automaton algorithm (from state X with input Y, goto state Z and accept or not) the only thing that changes is the table used for parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\d+[\.:]*\d*` is not anchored and matches partial substrings matching the pattern. Also, it matches `11.....:::::` like strings as `[.:]*` matches 0+ `.` or `:` chars.

You may use

```
^\d+(?:[.:]\d*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/34eznw/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:`  - start of  a non-capturing group matching

  - `[.:]` - one `.` or `:`
  - `\d*` -  0+ digits
- `)?` - 1 or 0 times
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: @RinoRaj Hi, can I ask for a favor? I think [this question was incorrectly marked as dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54761228/3832970). Could you please cast a reopen vote? (Please do not reply to the comment, I will remove it soon.)

Answer (score 1):

How about `\d([:.]\d?)?`? That should handle all the cases you mentioned.

Or `\d+([:.]\d*?)?` if you want to accept more than one digit in each number.

To only match if exact simply add `^` to the start and `$` to the end of the regular expression. Example:

```js
const regex = /^\d+([:.]\d*?)?$/

console.log(regex.test('2'))
console.log(regex.test('2:'))
console.log(regex.test('2.'))
console.log(regex.test('2:3'))
console.log(regex.test('2.3'))
console.log(regex.test('12:23'))
console.log(regex.test('23.34'))
console.log(regex.test('2:3:4'))
console.log(regex.test('2.3.4'))
```

Comment: no problem :). You dont need the least quantifier anyway, or do you?

Comment: @JamesCoyle I tried (/\d+([:.]\d*?)?/).test('2:2:'). I am getting the result as true. Actually it should fail.

Comment: That's because it has found it twice. `Regex.test` will return true if any part of the string matches. I've edited with a solution.

Comment: Now, it is next to identical  to my solution, while the `\d*?` lazy digit matching pattern makes it less efficient than with a greedy quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

**2:2**: is not getting matched completely, only the substring 2:2

To avoid this, just use the anchors ^ and $ like you used in the original pattern. Following is a working regex sample using your optimized regex with the anchors added - `/^\d+[.:]?\d*$/`, and here's a link to it https://regexr.com/47msc