# What is the correct way to make a regex that accepts all letters and a selection of characters?

Tags: java, android, regex

I need a Regex that accepts all letters(lowercase & uppercase), numbers and these characters/symbols ('-','_','@','.'). It is not required to be in the form of an Email address. The characters can be positioned anywhere in the word. It also should not accept spaces and the word length must be 8 or more.

This is what I have so far.

```
^(?=\S{8})[a-zA-Z]\w*(?:\.\w+)*(?:@\w+\.\w{2,4})?$
```

Comment: Try `^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]{8,}$`

Comment: `[\dA-Za-z_@.-]{8,}` surely?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the following regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]{8,}$
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]{8,}` - 8 or more ASCII letters, digits, `.`, `_`, `@` or `-`
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PWxCEE/1).

Watch out for `\w` in Android, it matches all Unicode letters and digits by default (but not in Java).

In Android/Java, when using it with `.matches()`, you may remove the `^` and `$` anchors as this method requires a full string match:

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]{8,}";
```

Comment: `[\\p{Alnum}._@-]{8,}` for the purists

Comment: `^[a-z@-Z0-9_.-]{8,}$` is even shorter

Answer (score 4):

```
[a-zA-Z._@\d-]{8,}
```

should do the trick. With additional boundaries that'd be `^[a-zA-Z._@\d-]{8,}$`.

```
^               Beginning of the line
[a-zA-Z._@\d-]  Group of the characters a-z, A-Z and ., -, _, @ as per your question as well as numbers (\d)
{8,}            8 to unlimited times
$               End of the word
```

You can try it out on regex101.com [here](https://regex101.com/r/RvIsFZ/5).

<s>An even shorter solution would be `[\w.@-]{8,}` using `\w` as shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RvIsFZ/4)</s> Not correct! Thanks to [@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) for the correction; see comments for more.

Comment: FYI,  `\d`, `\w` and other shorthand character classes in Android regex match all Unicode chars belonging to that class and *"`\w` as shortcut for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`"* is wrong in this context. The `-` inside a character class must be escaped or put t the start/end of the character class [as `[.-_]` will match many more chars than you'd expect](https://regex101.com/r/PWxCEE/2).

Comment: Yup, I just saw with the `-` that a second ago while I was fiddling with it. Updated the post and the link is about to follow. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: However I am unsure about the `\w` thing. I just checked [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern) and `\w` is listed the way I described it. Did I misunderstand anything there?

Comment: See *Predefined Character classes and POSIX character classes are in conformance with the recommendation of Annex C: Compatibility Properties of Unicode Regular Expression .* `\w` *A word character:* `[\p{Alpha}\p{gc=Mn}\p{gc=Me}\p{gc=Mc}\p{Digit}\p{gc=Pc}]`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another form for alphanumeric character:

```
^[[:alnum:]._@\-]{8,}$
```

Comment: Java regex does not recognize the POSIX class syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
You should use `\\p{Alnum}`